# Adobe Flash CS6 JSFL issue in Exporting Movieclip as Sprite Sheet

Tags: javascript

How to make use of JSFL Class API "SpriteSheetExporter.exportSpriteSheet()".Can someone please help me with a concrete example.There is no issue in exporting movieclip as spritesheet manually using flash cs6 latest feature "Generate Sprite Sheet" but if done using JSFL , i dont get output as expected using CS6 javascript API .url : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WSd5f4b6c52cfaa4b1-d3431961351cb0528c-8000.html.

Please help me with a small jsfl script example if possible.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: if you are using a Mac, there is a bug that prevents the sprite sheet generator to work using JSFL.   [Question on the AdobeForum](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4866036#4866036)

Answer (score 1):

```
var export = fl.spriteSheetExporter;
export.beginExport();
  export.addSymbol(fl.getgetDocumentDOM().getTimeline().layers[0].frames[0].elements[0].libraryItem);
export.layoutFormat = "JSON";
export.exportSpriteSheet("file///:c|users/test", "png");
```

Comment: you need to add some explanation with code then it become a good answer.